# Convert json object to ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Does anyone know how to turn a json object into a parseobject?

I've seen it done in a previous project like this:

```
T obj = ParseObject.fromJSON(data, resultClassName, true);
```

But when I try this in my project I get the following error message:

```
Error:(107, 46) error: 
method fromJSON in class ParseObject cannot be applied to given types;
  required: JSONObject,String,boolean,ParseDecoder
  found: JSONObject,String,boolean
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
where T is a type-variable:
T extends ParseObject declared in method <T>fromJSON(JSONObject,String,boolean,ParseDecoder)
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Thanks
Aidan

Comment: I don't think there is a static method ParseObject.fromJSON()... is there?

Comment: Its there but ive not seen a method like it. is that public or private?...
  /* package */ static <T extends ParseObject> T fromJSON(JSONObject json, String defaultClassName,
      boolean isComplete) {
    return fromJSON(json, defaultClassName, isComplete, ParseDecoder.get());
  }

Comment: Can't you just do `ParseObject.fromJSON([json]);`

Comment: Nah has to have the other properties init.